# Передать клик на радиокнопку

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Вот HTML

```
                                <div class="table_row">
                                    <div class="table_cell">
                                        <div class="radio_2">
                                            <input type="radio" name="gallery_radio" id="r_23" />
                                            <label for="r_23">09/05/2019</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table_cell">
                                        <p>200</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table_cell">
                                        <p>20 +</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table_cell">
                                        <p>56657</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Нужно чтобы при клике на table_row клик передался на radio_2 input. Как это сделать?
Вот макет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Надо повесить событие на то что вам надо и сделать checked radio_2

Comment: А если не заморачиваться с этим, и ту функцию, которая должна сработать при change радио - привязать к клику на весь блок?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".table_row").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var radioInput = $(this).find(".radio_2 input");
    if(radioInput.checked) {
        radioInput.prop("checked", "false");
    } else {
        radioInput.prop("checked", "true");
    }
});
```